# Formula-based conditional formatting to format cells in the same row

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a column that uses dropdowns for the user to select values. Depending on which value is selected, I want it to conditionally format other cells **in that same row**.

Here's an example of my sheet:

[image: Example sheet]

When a cell in the `Dropdown` column has the value "Selection One" I want cells in that same row highlighted in the `Color` and `Description` column. When a cell in the `Dropdown` column has the value "Selection Two" I want cells in that same row highlighted in the "Size" and "Description" column, and if the `Dropdown` column has the value "Selection Three" I want the cells in the `Color` and `Size` columns highlighted. Here's what I'd ultimately like it to appear:

[image]

I've tried various formulas, and the best I've been able to accomplish is formatting all cells in certain columns if *any* cell in the `Dropdown` column has, for example "Selection one", which obviously doesn't accomplish what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Can you clarify exactly what you've tried? Also, why isn't `C2` highlighted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- For `B2` and below, `=OR($A2="Selection One",$A2="Selection Three")`.
- For `C2` and below, `=OR($A2="Selection Two",$A2="Selection Three")`.
- For `D2` and below, `=OR($A2="Selection One",$A2="Selection Two")`.